# Elasticsearch how to set alert on total size of indices matching a pattern?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I would like to set an Alert Rule in Elastic - to trigger an alert when a total size of indices, matching a specific pattern, exceeds some limit.

I know how to get the total size by running a query:

```
GET /.ds-elastic-cloud-logs*/_stats
```

this would give me:

```
...
"_all": {
"primaries": {
  "docs": {
    "count": 12865686,
    "deleted": 0
  },
  "shard_stats": {
    "total_count": 5
  },
  "store": {
    "size_in_bytes": 2205540490,
    "total_data_set_size_in_bytes": 2205540490,
    "reserved_in_bytes": 0
  },
...
```

and the value I'm looking for is: **"size_in_bytes": 2205540490**

But I could not find how to create an alert based on this value...
I looked at the "index threshold" type of alerts: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/master/rule-type-index-threshold.html - and while I am able to specify the index pattern (.ds-elastic-cloud-logs*) in the rule - the "size-in-bytes" field is not available for use in the alert...

Also looked at the "elasticsearch query" type of alerts: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/master/rule-type-es-query.html - but I can only get a count of documents returned by a query to be used as the metric, not the size of indices ...

Any other way to achieve what I want?
Thank you!
Marina

Comment: Hi Marina, I assume the [large shard size alert](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/kibana-alerts.html#kibana-alerts-large-shard-size) is not something that you want ?

Comment: no, thank you, @Paulo, I need a total sum over all indices of a specific pattern, not single shards... as a workaround I got a total doc count alert working - but it is an estimate based on the number of docs I see now and their total size.